# In which of the following cases is $H$ a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

From Artin  Algebra Page no. $70$:

> In which of the following cases is $H$ a  subgroup of $G$ ?
>
> $a)\;$$ G= \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $H$  is the  set of  positive integer
>
> $b)\;$$G = \mathbb{R}^{×} $and $H$ is the set of positive reals

My attempts : I thinks  both a) and b)  will not form subgroup because $-1 \notin H,$ though it is inverse of $1$

Am I right ?

Comment: Even $G$ is not a group under addition. So $-1$ does not make sense for this question.

Comment: Yes, you may consider promoting your attempts to a self-answer, which can receive upvotes from others.

Comment: @DietrichBurde You're right, but [self-answering](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) is "explicitly encouraged" so that the system knows that OP's problem has been solved.

Comment: But OP's problem has not been solved, because the argument is not correct.

Comment: @DietrichBurde,,i don't  know  the  answer  can u give me any hints

Comment: @jasmine See the first comment for a hint. Consider $G$ as a group under *multiplication* for b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Artin use  the notation $\Bbb{Z}^+$   for **additive group of integers**  not  the set of positive integers. Similarly $\Bbb{R}^\times$ stands for multiplicative group of nonzero reals. Why I'm explaining this is  to clarify the notation, because some users misunderstand that in the comment.

Your argument works for a) not b)

Even the identity is not in $H$ in a) so it is not a subgroup

The $H$ in b) is actually the subgroup of $\Bbb{R}^\times$